# Error while upgrading to windows 10 pro

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-10, windows-error-reporting

I got a error while upgrading to windows 10 pro from windows 7 ultimate. It's a legal version! By restarting and loading win 10 pro he gave the blue screen error c1900101-20017 and then he restart to win 7 ultimate.

Does anyone know how to solve that problem?
The installer said that all apps are  fine.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Go to C: > Windows > Software Distribution > Download and delete all the files stored in this folder. Also delete the $Windows.~BT folder located in the root directory of "C:".

Step 2: As the Windows Update method seems to be a bit messy due to inherent bugs in the OS, it is advisable to try performing a clean install of Windows 10 by downloading the ISO files from Microsoft's official website. After downloading the ISO file, you need to create a bootable installation media via Microsoft's Media Creation tool.

Step 3: Once you have prepared the bootable USB drive or DVD, you can proceed with correcting a few settings in the BIOS menu.

Step 4: Reboot your computer and once the display appears, quickly tap the F12 or Delete key to bring up the BIOS menu.

Step 5: Disable all overclocking options for your processor, if you have set it higher than default values.

Step 6: Enable UEFI Boot from the BIOS, which can be found under the Boot section of the BIOS screen.

Step 7: Just reboot the computer via installation media you created earlier and the Windows 10 upgrade should complete without any hassles.
from:[here](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/windows-10-how-fix-blue-screen-death-error-c1900101-20017-during-installation-1513691)

Comment: But I was using the media creation tool already

Answer (score 0):

Anoniem,

Botmaster has a good point and covered the best-practice. I've had the same trouble with my 7 Pro x64 upgrade to 10. The first mistake is with the OS when setting up. If you're machine is x64, your install disc must be set that way (I was trying to install x32 onto an x64 when I got the error). There a few must-dos.

Critical: When you're on the OS that you wish to upgrade, download the "[[Media Creation Tool]](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install). If you haven't already done so, upgrade the system with the Media tool (ensure that you select the proper version so that Ultimate and either x32 or x64 is selected). Skip all requests for the product key: unless you were supplied one for Windows 10. I suggest remaining with the local account sign-in when prompted. When the installation completes, go to system and verify version. Windows should be Activated and you can begin the second part.

Now for the Clean Installation: get another "media creation tool", set it to download the proper version to create an ISO file. Once the file has been burned, and you have backed up all your data, shut the machine down and boot from the media (F12).

Critical: Reformat your drives (I suggest deleting and new), ignore the product key, use a local account. Once loaded, go to Updates, advanced options: choose automatic, make sure "Defer upgrades" and "Give me updates for other," is not selected. Also ensure that your drivers are not being downloaded automatically: Device Installation Settings. I disable because if I don't, the new version for my printer is downloaded, and I cannot install the working copy. Once you've installed all the files you can without signing into online services, save a recovery, and link your Microsoft account.

I also suggest verifying your installations after each point by running cmd: sfc /scannow with administer privileges. Keep creating restore points and scanning as you go along until you've reached your "System Image" that you should burn twice. One to hide in a safe place, the other to keep on hand. Remember: the more important the data, the higher the likelihood that something stupid will render it useless.

Good luck.